# Using mocha and chai to test outputs which are arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm new to testing Javascript, so this may be entirely obvious. I'm using the framework Mocha and the assertion library Chai to test a Javascript tool.

I have several functions which output an array with several elements. How does one use Chai to test this?

Here is an example:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;

// define an array
var Arr = [3, 4, 5, 6, 10];

console.log(Arr.slice(1, 3))
// outputs [4, 5]

// this will fail
describe('subsetting an array', function() {
  it('array subset', function() {
    assert.equal(Arr.slice(1, 3), [4, 5])
  });
});
```

So this test fails with the following error:

```
AssertionError: expected [ 4, 5 ] to equal [ 4, 5 ]
```

(1) Why does `assert.equal()` fail? These are both data structures of type "Array"

(2) How should one correctly test this with Chai?

Comment: I think you need to check for deep equality using .deepEqual http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepequal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert.equal()` tests comparison using `==`, and given that `slice()` creates a new array, although both have the same number of elements, they are not the same element (they are actually two different arrays, containing the same integers)

I think you should use [eql](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql) method

```
// Target array is deeply (but not strictly) equal to [1, 2]
expect([1, 2]).to.eql([1, 2]).but.not.equal([1, 2]);
```

See that there's a difference between `eql` and `equal`

If you want to stick to asssert, I think (I don't have the console here to test it) that you can use [deepEqual](http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#deepequalactual-expected-message)

```
assert.deepEqual({ tea: 'green' }, { tea: 'green' });
```

Not quite sure if it works for arrays, though

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm a bit confused by "expect([1, 2]).to.eql([1, 2]).but.not.equal([1, 2]);". What is added by using ".but.not.equal([1, 2])"?

Comment: just so you see the difference between eql and equal. Because that test will pass, and that's because it is not "equal" but it is "eql". You don't need that part for your test, just use eql